# Selecting image from GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

So what I have is a gridview being populated from images from my firebase database. What Im looking to do is be able to click one of the images from the gridview and have the image be full page (have its own layout). So this is inside my ProfileFragment and I have my full page for the photos setup in my ViewPicFragment. This is my setUpGridView in my ProfileFragment

```
private void setupGridView(){
Log.d(TAG, "setupGridView: Setting up image grid.");

final ArrayList<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = reference
        .child(getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for ( DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            photos.add(singleSnapshot.getValue(Photo.class));
        }
        //setup image grid
        int gridWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int imageWidth = gridWidth/NUM_GRID_COLUMNS;
        gridView.setColumnWidth(imageWidth);

        ArrayList<String> imgUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < photos.size(); i++){
            imgUrls.add(photos.get(i).getImage_path());
        }
        GridImageAdapter adapter = new GridImageAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.layout_grid_imageview,
                "", imgUrls);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: query cancelled.");
    }
});
}
```

Im just at a loss right now on where to go in the onItemClickListener. Forgive me if some of the code isnt the greatest, Im still pretty new to Java. If you all need to see anymore code, Id gladly post more. Just thought this was the necessary code.

Comment: Referred link show you how can you show the gridview image in Full screen after click on the gridview image

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Let me know it help you or not.

Comment: @vishalgole It did help. I got it to work when I switched my ViewPicFragment to an Activity instead of a fragment.